# How to make an audio player widget in android

Tags: android, widget, android-mediaplayer

I want to make an audio player widget in which I have added there buttons for play , next and previous.Widget should show title  progress of song on seek bar and image if any available for the same.

I am unable to find how I can play songs ,can go to previous or next  song and how to show the progress on seek bar through my audio widget.

Following is my AppWidgetProvider class that I have created for this.

```
public class AudioMusicWIdgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    public static String ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER = "PLAYActionReceiverWidget";
    TextView songTitle;
    ArrayList<Song>arrayList;
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.musicplayerwidget);

        Toast.makeText(context, "onUpdate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        getSongsList(context);

        Intent action = new Intent(context, AudioMusicWIdgetProvider.class);
        action.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);
        action.putExtra("msg", "This starts playing");
        PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, action, 0);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.songTitle,"");
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnPlay,
                actionPendingIntent);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnNext,
                actionPendingIntent);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnPrevious, actionPendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // v1.5 fix that doesn't call onDelete Action
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED.equals(action)) {
            //The widget is being deleted off the desktop
            final int appWidgetId = intent.getExtras().getInt(
                    AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                    AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
            if (appWidgetId != AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
                this.onDeleted(context, new int[]{appWidgetId});
            }
        } else {
            // check, if our Action was called
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER)) {

                //Play the audio file
                //The audio file is in /res/raw/ and is an OGG file
               playAudio(arrayList.get(0).getPath());
            } else {
                // do nothing
            }


            super.onReceive(context, intent);
        }
    }


    public  void getSongsList(Context context){
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        Uri songUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor songCursor = contentResolver.query(songUri, null, null, null, null);

        if(songCursor != null && songCursor.moveToFirst()){
              Song song = new Song();
             int songId =songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);

            int songTitle = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int artist = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            int duration = songCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION);
            do {
                song.setSongId((int) songCursor.getLong(songId));
                song.setTitle(songCursor.getString(songTitle));
                song.setSinger(songCursor.getString(artist));
                song.setDuration(songCursor.getString(duration));
                song.setPath(songCursor.getString(songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)));
                arrayList.add(song);
            }while(songCursor.moveToNext());
        }

    }


    public static void playAudio(final String path) {
        final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
        if (path == null) {
           // Log.e(LOGGING_TAG, "Called playAudio with null data stream.");
            return;
        }
        try {
            player.setDataSource(path);
            player.prepare();
            player.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          //  Log.e(LOGGING_TAG, "Failed to start MediaPlayer: " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for like this https://github.com/Cleveroad/MusicBobber